# How do I remove files from the Xcode prompt once I have already deleted them?

Tags: xcode

This file is stuck, I have deleted it and it won't go away. I have already tried to remake the file but no avail, it is the JavaFileJa. I misnamed it and I can't get it to go away.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking File->Open Recent->Clear Menu in Xcode's menu bar will remove all of your recent project history.

If you really need to only remove a single item, it's a bit more complicated.  See [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/293647/377070) for instructions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to mac and that was bugging me!